# I have a short CT video of a BuffaloFish and i need to manipluate the Frames from the video to make a 3D model of the animals skeleton

Tags: image3d

I know i need to use Image3D but other than that, im not exactly sure on where to start?

https://youtu.be/yPTEs6jE6B4

heres a link to the video.

Comment: i have the video but i didnt know how to put a link of it into mathematica

Answer (score 5):

[`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html) allowsyou to stack an image sequence.

I converted your video into a 320 x240 gif and imported the image sequence.
My machine crashes for anything but "vanilla" color functions. Perhaps other answers will be more instructive. The gif is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp38f.jpg) should others wish to play with.

An example of code (dropping initial frames):

```
gif = Import["e:/movies/fish.gif"];
cull = gif[[10 ;;]];
Image3D[cull, "Byte", ColorFunction -> "HighRange"]
```

Various colorfunctions:

"Xray":

[image]
"HighRange":

[image]

[image]

`(Append[Blend[{LightBlue, Blue, Orange}, #], #] &)`:

[image]